# ng-click on CellTemplate not working in angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a UI-grid I want click on cell values.

This is my Code

User.js

```
var app = angular.module("myApp");
app.controller("userController", function ($scope) {

$scope.number;
var myData = [{
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
 }, {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
 }, {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
 },
    {
        "firstName": "Priyanka",
        "lastName": "Taneja",
        "company": "GE",
        "employed": true
 },
    {
        "firstName": "Ashish",
        "lastName": "Grover",
        "company": "Deloitte",
        "employed": true
 }

             ];

$scope.count = function () {
    $scope.number = 3;
}
$scope.gridOptions = {

    enableColumnMenus: false,

    enableSorting: true,
    columnDefs: [
        {
            name: 'firstName',
            width: "25%",
            displayName: 'FirstName(' +
                $scope.number + ')',
            cellTemplate: '<div  ng-click="grid.appScope.count()" ng-bind="row.entity.firstName"></div>'
        },
        {
            name: 'lastName',
            width: "25%",
            displayName: 'LastName'

        },
        {
            name: 'company',
            width: "25%",
            displayName: 'Company'

        },
        {
            name: 'employed',
            width: "25%",
            displayName: 'Employed'

        }

        ]
}

$scope.gridOptions.data = myData;
```

});

[image]
User.html

```
      <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="userController">
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid"></div>
```

I want to click on the cell. And i want value of no to be displayed along with FirstName where value is coming as undefined. How can i fix this thing.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: No, not yet solved

Comment: did you try updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

can you try to change this

```
displayName: 'FirstName(' +
            $scope.number + ')',
```

into

```
displayName: 'FirstName({{number}})',
```

Comment: No it is not working. I am able to click using this $scope.count = function () {
    $scope.number = 3;
} But $scope.number value initially it is 0 m updating to 3. But its not updating the value.

Comment: Did you add console.log inside function, did it work

Comment: It worked but the issue is in Firstname(count) initially count is undefined so it is showing undefined on click m updating the count but UI its still undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You never set the value of `$scope.number;`. When the grid loads, it looks for something there, and it's undefined.

Try something like this:

```
displayName: 'FirstName' + ($scope.number ? '(' + $scope.number + ')' : ''),
```

That uses a ternary operator. Basically it says "if $scope.number is defined, then display it (along with the parenthesis), otherwise, display just *FirstName*.